# Azure jobs aborting

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have enable always on property in configuration, still long running jobs are aborting.

I have running 10 long running jobs concurrently in one Web APP. For Web App plan is standard. As per standard plan we can schedule 50 jobs in one web app. still I am facing issue of abort. That it wont abort all the jobs it will abort 3 to 4 jobs which are taking more CPU throughput. It will be great if any body come with answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code please ? Or explain a little bit more

Comment: I have running 10 web jobs in azure. So In that 10 Jobs 4 to 5 jobs will abort after some time. It is not loging anywhere. How to fix this.

Comment: All 10 jobs are long running jobs. They may run 10hour 12hour 24 hour like that

Comment: you may have some timeout. Increase the value of this setting WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT.

Comment: Also, please specify if jobs are triggered or continuous.